# c++ globlal/stack instance ctor/dtor crashing when call static function

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a class defined in the same file of main, another class(full of static functions/members) defined in 2 seperate files, and it crashes. I guess this may be relevant to the lifetime of global/static instance. it seems that in the ctor, the static member has not been initialized, and it may happends that when exit, the static member is freed before the first instance is destructed.
here is the test code:

```
    //testh.h
    #include <map>
    class Sc {
    public:
        static void insert();
        static void out();

    private:
        static std::map<int, int> map_;
    };

    //testcpp.cpp
    #include "testh.h"
    #include <iostream>
    std::map<int, int> Sc::map_;

    void Sc::insert() {
        map_.insert(std::make_pair(2,3));
    }

    void Sc::out() {
        for(auto m : map_) {
            std::cout << m.first << ' ' << m.second << '\n';
        }
    }

    //main.cpp
    #include "testh.h"
    class Nc {
    public:
        Nc() {
            Sc::insert();
            Sc::out();
        }
        ~Nc() {
            Sc::insert();
            Sc::out();
        }
    };

    Nc nc;
    int main() {

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

here are some strange behaviours of the above code:

if I replace the staic member to int, it will not crash, so I suppose there may be problems with std::map?

if I put all the codes into main.cpp, it will not crash, but wouldn't these generates the same codes?

how to solve this problem if I don't want to do dynamic allocation(new)?

Comment: you have two `class Sc`, one in main.cpp another in testh.h ?

Comment: I can guarantee there is no problem with anything in std.

Comment: @billz it's another class Nc in main.cpp, Sc in testcpp.cpp/testh.h

Comment: You don't have a destructor in testcpp.cpp. Could that be a reason? Maybe destroying the map would help.

Comment: @lost_with_coding map_ is not a pointer, how do I destroy it? it's static, will be recycled automatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you do not know what order th global variables will be constructed in:

This

```
// test.cpp
std::map<int, int> Sc::map_;
```

And this

```
//main.cpp
Nc nc;
```

Because these are in different compilation units the standard does not guarantee the order they will be created in. Thus if `nc` is created first then any attempt to use `Sc::map_` will fail (and `nc` does use this via its calls to the statics).

When you put the globals into one file:

```
//main.cpp
std::map<int, int> Sc::map_;
Nc nc;
```

Then the order is guaranteed. It is the order of declaration. So as long as you put `Sc::map_` first then it will all work.

There is a simple technique to get around this::

Replace this:

```
private:
    static std::map<int, int> map_;
};
```

With:

```
private:
    static std::map<int, int>& getMap()
    {
        static std::map<int, int> instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

But the real problem is that you are using global mutable state (global variables). Try not to use them at all. It tightly binds your code to the globl state. You should be passing state to methods with parameters or via objects that know how to retrieve the state.

Comment: so is there any way to make sure the static member is destroyed at the end of the process?

Comment: static members are always correctly destroyed. "Static Storage Duration" objects are destroyed in the reverse order of creation after main exits.

Comment: @BЈовић: Yep. As usual parashift is completely useless. As it does not tell you how to solve the problem correctly. I completely hate that website as it is full of subtle mistakes and misinformation. There solution to this problem is crap (it leaks).

Comment: @LokiAstari [it does](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html)

Comment: @BЈовић: Its a bad solution. As it leaks. Thus in my opinion wrong and not a solution.

Comment: @BЈовић: Another great one: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html can you even spot the error here.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, another question, will the dtor always be called safely in my situation? if not, should I write a particular method to do the static call before exit?

Comment: @LokiAstari Oh, you are right about the leak. At the placement new link, I do not see anything wrong. Can you point it out?

Comment: @BЈовић: The use of `char memory[sizeof(Fred)]` is not guaranteed to be aligned for anything but char. That is pointed out in the danger section. But there is an easy solution. By using `memory = new char[sizeof(Fred)]` you get memory that is guaranteed to be aligned correctly for any object of `sizeof(Fred)` (or smaller). So now we have a memory leak problem. By just using RAII principles we wrap the `new`. `std::vector<char> buffer(sizeof(Fred));char* memory = &buffer[0];`. The point here is that (generally) placement new should be used with a dynamically allocated buffer for alignment.

Comment: @BЈовић: My point is: parashift has lots of info (lots of it good). But sometimes the criticisms are overblown as the standard techniques for doing stuff in C++ guide you around these problems (they may be gotchas for beginners learning by themselves but any experienced developer is not going to fall into these trap as that is not how you write C++). Also I find a lot of the code is suspect (not all). But I found two quickly last night (I had seen the placement new one before). But it took me a second to spot the leak.